# Make sure newest data takes precedent in SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have a loop with the following query at the bottom, it's changing the column value in `updated_in_sib` to `1` when it matches the `customer_id`:

```
$wpdb->update('imp_customer_log', ['updated_in_sib' => 1], ['customer_id' => $customer_id]);
```

This is my database setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `imp_customer_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_in_sib` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=74 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

At the moment rows are getting added (there can be multiple rows for the same data) but the query has picked the oldest `id` row so when a new row is added with newer data it's getting ignored.

**How can I pick the newest row?**

E.g The data in a row with the `id` 72 was used over the row with the `id` 73, 73 is obviously the newer data.

For some context, here's my full code that's looping through each row:

```
// Update SiB contact hourly
function sendinblue_update() {
  global $wpdb;

  $customer_data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM imp_customer_log WHERE updated_in_sib = '0'");
    foreach( $customer_data as $customer ) {

        $customer_id = $customer->customer_id;
    $customer_event = $customer->event;
    $customer_data = $customer->data;

        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $customer_id );
        $user_email = $user->user_email;

        $data_in = array(
            $customer_event => $customer_data,
        );
        $result = $this->sendinblue_update_user($user_email, $data_in);

        $wpdb->update('imp_customer_log', ['updated_in_sib' => 1], ['customer_id' => $customer_id]);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `get_results` query I've just reversed the array to take the latest:

```
$customer_data = array_reverse($customer_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from imp_customer_log icl where icl.customer_id = 'xxx' 
and icl.id = (select max(icl2.id) from imp_customer_log icl2 where icl2.customer_id = 'xxx')
```

or

```
select max(id) from imp_customer_log where customer_id = xxx
```

this will always get you the latest row considering id is auto increment

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`, if you do a select on a criteria that matches multiple rows. You're not saying which query 'picked the oldest id"